# Variable inside subprocess.check_output argument ? [Python]

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

simple question:

why this doesnt work?

```
test = 2

print subprocess.check_output(["program",
                               "-v",
                               "-a5",
                               "-t%i",   <----------
                               "-oURL",
                               "-uUSER",
                               "-pPASS"]) % (test)
```

with "-t1" or other value, it work perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean to do this?

```
print subprocess.check_output(["program",
                               "-v",
                               "-a5",
                               "-t%i" % test,
                               "-oURL",
                               "-uUSER",
                               "-pPASS"])
```

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, quite so -- as I quickly realized!

Answer (score 1):

you need `"-t%i" % test,`

Answer (score 1):

We can build the command first and then use subprocess.check_output
For example-

```
command = "program -v -a5 -t{} -oURL -uUSER -pPASS".format(test)

print subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
```